# Move ignored directory to other branch

Tags: git, github, gradle, branch

I'm currently working on a project which uses Gradle. The project repository is on GitHub and there are two main branches: `master` for the actual source files and `gh-pages` for, well, the GitHub pages. They are completely independent from each other and have unrelated histories.

Now I want to host the documentation files (i.e. the JavaDoc files) on the GitHub pages site, so I need to put the generated documentation files on the `gh-pages` branch. However, the directory where the documentation goes after building is ignored on the `master` branch since I don't want to push it to the main repository branch - only to the GitHib pages branch.

So once I checkout to the `gh-pages`, the generated files are gone (overwritten by the ones in the documentation branch, respectively).

Is there any way to move (merge, checkout, ...) *ignored* documentation files from the `master` branch to the GitHub pages branch without needing to move them out of the repository before switching branches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like `git stash` could do what you want to:

**Step 1:** You generate your docs

**Step 2:** `git status` shows that you have made changes in `docs/...`

**Step 3:** You fire up `git add docs/` followed by `git stash` and git will take note of all the changes but restore the working environment to your last commit

**Step 4:** You switch to gh-pages using `git checkout gh-pages`

**Step 5:** You apply the changes you have made to the docs using `git stash pop`

**Step 6:** You can commit those changes.

For short: `git stash` cleans everything so you can switch branches but it remembers the changes and you can "merge" them again on top of the other branch. You can also create multiple stashes but it will get messed up soon, so be sure to use `git stash pop` which will not just apply the latest changes but also remove them from its stashing-index.

Comment: I had to force the `git add`, since the directory is ignored on master but then it worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ah yes, this makes sense if you've added `docs` to your `.gitignore` No problem!